# Make 'New Address' as selected when 'Same as Shipping Address' is unchecked

Tags: checkout

I want to make 'New Address' as the selected option by default when we uncheck the 'Same as Shipping Address' option during checkout, instead of selecting the saved addresses in profile.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Try by js improvement or by xml configuration.